# How to use Utilities in static pages

Tags: cakephp

I want to use `File` and `Folder` Utilities to list files in a folder (which is located in `webroot` directory)

It's so easy to do it in a controller action, but how can I use them a static page? (which there's no action in `PagesController` for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that just like in a controller. Load the Classes with `App::uses()` and create an instance. It works everywhere inside of CakePHP (model, controller, helper, component, view, ...).

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html for details.